# Where can I find the database for Expo-Sqlite? It's for my React Native activity

Tags: database, react-native, expo-sqlite

I am looking for the db file so that I can edit it with the db browser.

I tried looking for it but couldn't seem to find it. I heard that it's impossible to find with "expo-sqlite" instead of "react-native-sqlite-storage".

Answer (score 0):

As for the [expo-sqlite docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/) looks like you need to configure sqlite server on your machine using [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

> SQLite is a C-language library that implements a small, fast,
> self-contained, high-reliability, full-featured, SQL database engine.
> SQLite is the most used database engine in the world. SQLite is built
> into all mobile phones and most computers and comes bundled inside
> countless other applications that people use every day.

Once you'll do that you'll be able to access your db using the following script:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';

async function openDatabase(pathToDatabaseFile: string): Promise<SQLite.WebSQLDatabase> {
  if (!(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite')).exists) {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite');
  }
  await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
    Asset.fromModule(require(pathToDatabaseFile)).uri,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/myDatabaseName.db'
  );
  return SQLite.openDatabase('myDatabaseName.db');
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I do that if im using android studio emulator?

Comment: First you need to configure sqlite on you machine. than, when the sqlite server is running you'll be able to access it. than run it from your react native code. not from the android activity.  if you want it to run only from your android native side than you need to write the java code on your own and make it accessible from your react native code.

Comment: How do I configure the sqlite? I'm a pretty newbie at this. Sorry about that.

Comment: You can follow the instructions here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/  let me know if you need more help